# throttling http requests google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request, throttling

As it turns out the answer to my prior question does not work.  The problem is that I am overloading the server with requests.  The process needs a throttle so that subsequent requests incur a little slowdown.  Here is the code in question.  The important segment of code that needs a timer or setInterval is that prefaced by the alert "Profile Rejected" although it would be acceptable to slow them both down.  Any suggestions?

```
if (greetThisOne==true && !bGreeted)
{
    //alert ("Requesting Message Page");
    console.log="Message Page Requested";
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "openMessage", url: messageLink, keyWordsFound: keyWordList, greeted: bGreeted});    
}
else 
{
    //alert("Profile Rejected");
    console.log="Profile Rejected";
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "profileRejected", url: messageLink, keyWordsFound: keyWordList, greeted: bGreeted});
}
```

Comment: What's the problem or question then?  You tried a timer but it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to implement some queue in the background page. For example:

```
var rejectedProfiles = [];
processRejectedProfiles();

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "profileRejected") {
        //add to the end of queue
        rejectedProfiles.push({url: request.url, other: request.parameters});
    }
    sendResponse({});
});

function processRejectedProfiles() {
    if(rejectedProfiles.length > 0) {
        //get the oldest element in queue
        var profile = rejectedProfiles.shift();

        //process profile
        ...
    }

    //process next entry in the queue in 3 seconds
    setTimeout(processRejectedProfiles, 3000);
}
```

This way you will be processing one profile at a time, with a provided delay.

Comment: That's a very elegant solution.